# jquery animation and binding

Tags: jquery

I have some jQuery that is dynamically creating a span element with a certain shape defined by css. The span elements are generated at a random x,y location on the screen and I have defined them with class=".drawingpix". A new span element identical to the last, except it's location is created every second or two. I want to be able to animate the element when clicked. So far I have only be able to animate all of the elements when the body is clicked.

What I want to happen: I would like to animate the element when touched or clicked and only that one element.

This gets me nothing when in the head:

```
    $('.drawingpix').click(function () {
    // this is the dom element clicked?????
    var element = this;
    $(this).animate({
        height:'250px',
        width:'250px',
        'border-radius':'250px',
        '-moz-border-radius': '250px',
        '-webkit-border-radius': '250px',
        opacity: -0.2,
            }, 3000).fadeOut(0);    
});
```

This animates every element with the class 'drawingpix' when in the body but nothing when in the head.:

```
    $('body').click(function () {
    // this is the dom element clicked?????
    var element = this;
    $('.drawingpix').animate({
        height:'250px',
        width:'250px',
        'border-radius':'250px',
        '-moz-border-radius': '250px',
        '-webkit-border-radius': '250px',
        opacity: -0.2,
            }, 3000).fadeOut(0);    
});
```

I am new to jquery and javascript. I have done hours of searching and trying different things before I have posted here.

I think I need to some how get the index of the element I clicked and specify which element to animate based off of the index. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you try delegating the event and see if that approach works for newly created elements..

```
 $('body').on('click', '.drawingpix' ,function () {
    // this is the dom element clicked?????
    var element = this;
    $(this).animate({
        height:'250px',
        width:'250px',
        'border-radius':'250px',
        '-moz-border-radius': '250px',
        '-webkit-border-radius': '250px',
        opacity: -0.2,
            }, 3000).fadeOut(0);    
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That worked and I am now learning about delegating. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you're encountering a gotcha that almost every new jQuery user experiences. For most event-handlers, like `click()`, you have to wait for the DOM to be ready. jQuery makes this pretty painless, via the [jQuery.ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) function. The function expects you to pass a function to it containing code you'd like invoked once the DOM is ready. So, for example, your code would look like:

```
jQuery.ready(function(){
    $('.drawingpix').click(function(){
        // this is the dom element clicked?????
        var element = this;
        $(this).animate({
            height:'250px',
            width:'250px',
            'border-radius':'250px',
            '-moz-border-radius': '250px',
            '-webkit-border-radius': '250px',
            opacity: -0.2,
        }, 3000).fadeOut(0);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with the contents of your `click` handler; it should only apply to the element being clicked.  However, there are some subtleties you have to observe when dynamically creating elements.  When you set up handlers, they are only applied to objects *currently in the DOM*.  If you create a new element after that, they will not have the click handler, which may be the issue you are experiencing.

jQuery has a solution for that: the [`live()` function](http://api.jquery.com/live/).  Not only does this attach the handler for elements currently in the DOM, it attaches it to all matching elements *in the future*.  So it's exactly what you need.  You just need to modify your code like this:

```
$('.drawingpix').live('click',function () {
    $(this).animate({
        height:'250px',
        width:'250px',
        'border-radius':'250px',
        '-moz-border-radius': '250px',
        '-webkit-border-radius': '250px',
        opacity: -0.2,
        }, 3000).fadeOut(0);    
});
```

Here's a working jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QUFGQ/